# How to create a script that loads a desktop link and changes the icon?

Tags: remote-desktop, desktop, group-policy, windows-server-2019

Long story short, Windows Server 2022: While this SHOULD be done via GPO, we're having a few issues with GPO and our server right at the moment.

But the location where the proper GPO options are, is not the server that needs the icon.

Our server setup :

SERVER00 [Physical] SERVER01 [Active Directory, Hyper-V, Fileshares, & GPO] SEVER04 [RDP server]

Setting the GPO on SERVER01 did exactly what we wanted... but only on SERVER01. SERVER04 is where it needs to be, and we can't figure out how to get the GPO generated on 01 to produce the desired result on 04 : Note that all other GPO policies do get enforced from 01 on 04.

So the idea is to have a script that loads the proper links on certain user's (all part of a dedicated security group) desktops, removes another link, and changes the link icon.

The specific use case is to get people to stop using Outlook Application, and start using it on 365. So what we want to do, is have a specific security group that when these users log in the Outlook application icon will be removed, a link to the 365 Outlook Login will be placed on the desktop, and the Icon will be set to the Outlook Icon.

Anyone have any resources or thoughts?

Comment: Do you have Active Directory?

Comment: Sorry, but your question needs to be described better so we can understand it.

Comment: @user996142 Yes we run Active Directory.

Comment: Then you can use GPO to install any icon on any computer on domain. Just use AD GPO, not Server01 GPO